# Why does the following code compile with MSVC++?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++11, decltype

```
struct X{};

template<class T>
decltype(X() == int()) f(T const&){ return true; }

int main(void) {
  X x;
  f(x);
}
```

Why, just *why*? There is no `operator==` defined *anywhere*!

I really want to understand what's going on here, to provide a detailed bug report on MS Connect. My journey to insanity began around [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3791988#3791988) in the Lounge<C++> chat room...

(Note: Neither [GCC](http://ideone.com/JV6Co) nor Clang accept this code.)

Oh, and btw, adding a private `X(int)` ctor causes the compilation to fail:

```
struct X{
    X(){}
private:
    X(int);
};

template<class T>
decltype(X() == int()) f(T const&){ return true; }

int main(void) {
  X x;
  f(x);
}
```

Output:

```
1>src\main.cpp(12): error C2248: 'X::X' : cannot access private member declared in class 'X'
1>          src\main.cpp(4) : see declaration of 'X::X'
1>          src\main.cpp(1) : see declaration of 'X'
```

Comment: Do other compilers accept it?

Comment: @Billy: Nope, added that info. Background info: I nearly went insane on what MSVC does here in the C++ chatroom and gave up after a couple of hours.

Comment: Added a bit of background info. Also, could the anonymous downvoter please voice the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Have you tried the same expression somewhere where it would actually be evaluated? Just curious..

Comment: @K-ballo: I added a link to the chat transcript, and we tried all sorts of things. If you add the expression *anywhere* else, except to a trailing return type, (or even remove the template), MSVC refuses to compile.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the body of `f`? Maybe for some reason it's trying to deduce the return type from the body of the function, ignoring the decltype. What happens if you make it returns something different from `true`?

Comment: @sbabbi: Returning anything that can't be converted to `bool` causes a compilation error.

Comment: does == need to be defined for everything? Is it possible it is defined automatically?

Comment: Are you really asking *why are there bugs in compilers*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of MS VC++ are you using?

For whatever it may be worth, VC++11 Beta rejects your code with:

```
trash.cpp(8): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type' f(const T &)'
          With the following template arguments:
          'X'
```

I'm not sure that's what I'd call the most helpful or informative error message ever, but it *is* rejecting the code.

Under the circumstances, I'd guess filing a bug report is probably going to accomplish little (if anything). The response I'd expect would be essentially: "Already fixed in VC++11. Upgrade when you can."

Comment: And here I was thinking that I was actually using the VS11 beta... What exact version do you have? Mine's "Version 11.0.40825.2 PREREL".

Comment: @Xeo: Version 11.0.50214.1 BETAREL". If I'm not mistaken you have the Technology Preview rather than the beta.

Comment: Well, so much for that. Gonna download the *real* beta and check back later, thanks.

Comment: @Xeo, actually the latest release is `QRELB`. It's an auto update for `BETAREL`: http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2012/04/2012-updates-to-microsoft-visual-studio.html